# Autoupdatable dependency

Tags: python, pip

I have a library that gets updates from time to time. I'd like users to use latest version. And I *don't* want them to do `pip install` every single time. What are possible workarounds?

Ideally, that should be bundled in `pip`, just like `-SNAPSHOT` feature in java world. Creating a wrapper over runner that checks for latest version sounds like reinventing a wheel, and I'd prefer to not do that.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say you don't want users to `pip install` every time -- is the problem the user action or the actual command?

Comment: That complicates workflow. Instead of `python foo.py` user would have to think about pip.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that considering safety and security, any trick for autoupdating a dependency should require consentment of the user in some way.

The trick to emulate the `-SNAPSHOT` feature from the java world is to `pip install` from a Git repo. You still need to trigger the pip install in some way, however, so you'll need that wrapper.

Comment: Totally agree with first part, that's why `-SNAPSHOT` prefix has to be provided explicitly. Could you elaborate about `pip install git+` thing, it does `git pull` every time, or how that works?

Comment: @dveim I believe you need to pass `--upgrade` to ensure it will download a new version every time: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support